# Not Bruce Wayne! Carry On!

Tags: wordplay, lateral-thinking

Another advennture! The three overlapping ellipses form seven curved regions - your task is to place one tile in each region so that the tiles in any one ellipse can be re-arranged into an eight-letter solution to the corresponding clue!
[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Fatality

> **CASUALTY**; All fatalities (deaths caused due to wars, accidents, etc.) are also casualties (which includes people who are injured as well).

Bruce?

> The [movie](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0315327/) Bruce **ALMIGHTY** with Jim Carrey.

Jane?

> [Martha Jane Cannary](https://www.britannica.com/biography/Calamity-Jane-American-frontierswoman), better known as **CALAMITY** Jane, was an American frontierswoman, sharpshooter, and storyteller. This is the only one I had to Google, I had the word but not the connection.

Solution

> [image]